# Convert character to datetime with R

Tags: r, datetime

after loading a table from R, I need to convert several variables in useful data.
Let's say the column I want to change's name is `mydata[[2]][6]`.
This list has char data, for instance `"42255.7298611111"`, and according to Openoffice, that value corresponds with `08/09/2015 17:31:00`.

As far as I've seen, in other variables like `mydata[[2]][3]`, where data is just for dates, data `"42260"` is easily converted to `09/14/2015` just by using:

```
mydata[[2]][3]  <- list(as.Date(strtoi(unlist(mydata[[2]][3])), origin="1900-01-01"))
```

Any guess about how to solve date-time problem?

Thanks in advanced! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Open office here, so I used excel instead.

You could use the following function:

```
function(t) as.POSIXct((t-1)*86400, origin="1900-01-01", tz="GMT")
```

(the t-1 is because excel seems to think that `origin=1900-01-00`, but that is not allowed in R, 86400 is the number of seconds in a day since as.POSIXct is expecting seconds since origin as argument).

This will however give an error of one day, which I think I have tracked down to day 60 (which according to excel is 1900-02-29, but as far as I can see 1900 was not a leap year). To fix this I guess that you could take `t-2` instead (at least if you are not concerned with dates that old).